# Testing ModalController Ionic 3 spyOn method not called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, ionic3

I am trying to test a method that launch a modal, has anybody done this before, can someone perhaps point me in the right direction?? I have written the following test suite.

```
describe('bdb modal provider test suite', () => {

let bdbModal: BdbModalProvider;
let modal: Modal;
let modalCtrl: ModalController;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            BdbModalProvider,
            { provide: ModalController, useClass: ModalControllerMock }
        ]
    });
    bdbModal = TestBed.get(BdbModalProvider);
    modalCtrl = TestBed.get(ModalController);
});

beforeEach(() => {
    modal = modalCtrl.create('ModalErrorPage', {});
});

it('should launch error modal', () => {
    spyOn(modal, 'present');
    bdbModal.launchErrModal('testing', 'error modal', 'OK');
    expect(modal.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
});
```

this is the error log:

> should launch error modal
>        bdb modal provider test suite
>        Expected spy present to have been called.
>       at UserContext. (webpack:///src/providers/bdb-modal/bdb-modal.spec.ts:31:30 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:140545:31)

Comment: What does `modalCtrl.create('ModalErrorPage', {})` return?

Comment: An instance of a Modal object

Comment: I am pretty sure is returning any instance of Modal, but I need the real instance, how to get it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### 1. Create Spy of modal and modal controller.

```
    modalSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Modal', ['present']);
    modalCtrlSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ModalController', ['create']);
    modalCtrlSpy.create.and.callFake(function () {
        return modalSpy;
    });
```

### 2. Add it's entry in test bed as below:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({

      declarations: [
        ..............
      ],

      providers: [
        ..............

        {
          provide: ModalController,
          useValue: modalCtrlSpy
        }
        ..............
      ],

      imports: [
        ............
      ]

    }).compileComponents();

  }));
```

### 3. Test case should be like below:

```
it('#display() should display modal', () => {
    .........
    expect(modalSpy.present).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
    .........
});
```

Comment: modal.onDidDismiss().then((d: any) => {
      // this.getInboxCollection()
      console.log('modal dismissed');
    });

May I have test cases  for this @Yuvraj

Comment: modal.onDidDismiss.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));

add this line for onDidDismiss

Comment: for modal close May I have test cases for this? @Yuvraj

Comment: @RaviAshara Add close method in array of method names (similar to `present` method).
Then add test case like mentioned in step 3 (replace modalSpy.present with modalSpy.close). It should work.

Comment: Hey @YuvrajPatil I am not able to pass my test case based on above implementation. Can you guide me what's wrong in my code? Error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dismiss')`