# Importing IonicModule.forRoot() in tests, causes them to fail if more then one test is run in the suite

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jasmine

I am using ionic with angular and doing unit tests with jasmine. I have a unit test for a component that looks something like this:

```
describe('ExercisePage', () => {
    ...

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                IonicModule.forRoot(),
                ...
            ],
            providers: [
                ...
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        
        ...
    });


    it('test 1', () => {
        ...
    });
    
    it('test 2', () => {
    ...
    });
})
```

I need to import `IonicModule.forRoot()` since my component is using the `ModalController` and that doesn't seem to work if I just import `IonicModule`.

- If I run each test alone (using `fit`) they pass
- If I run the tests without calling `forRoot` they pass (except the test that require `ModalController` to work)
- If I run all the tests the first one pass but for the rest I get some weird errors. Like `innerText` return an empty string, or a string with extra spaces etc.

Am I doing something wrong? How do I make all the tests work as expected?

---

If someone wants to deep-dive, since this project is open source I can share the actual code: https://github.com/ShacharHarshuv/open-ear/pull/70/files (Have a look at exercise.page.spec.ts)

Comment: I think instead of importing `IonicModule.forRoot` for `ModalController`, you should mock `ModalController`. Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50829780/7365461.

Comment: @AliF50 But if I mock ModalController, the modal wouldn't be opened. My test check that something is displayed on the screen after I click a button. That something is part of a modal.
Also, that doesn't explain that weird behavior