# Integration testing an ionic modal with Jasmine in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jasmine, integration-testing

I'm trying to test the integration between my angular page and a component running in a modal. The modal is given some data and the component:

```
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: EditPositionModalComponent,
      componentProps: {orderPosition}
    });
    await modal.present();

    // Wait for the modal to close and process the received data
    let {data} = await modal.onDidDismiss();
```

Inside the modal the user can edit the data and submit the changes. With the tests I want to make sure that the data gets sent correctly to the modal and back to the page after it's dismissed.

This is how far I got:

```
describe('OrderDetailPage/EditPosition Integrationtest', async () => {
  let component: OrderDetailPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OrderDetailPage>;
  let modalControllerSpy : Spy;

  beforeEach((() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [OrderDetailPage],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveComponentModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        //Providing mocks
        provideMockStore({}),
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrderDetailPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    modalControllerSpy = spyOn(ModalController.prototype, 'create').and.callThrough();
    component.onEditPosition(new MouseEvent(''), testOrderPosition); //Click event call to open the modal
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should send correct data to modal', async () => {
    let modal: HTMLIonModalElement = await modalControllerSpy.calls.first().returnValue;
    await modal.present();
  });
});
```

I can get the HTMLIonModalElement created from the modalController through the spy. But I can't find a way to access the actual component doing this. The HTMLIonModalElement only contains the following:

```
<ion-modal class="md modal-default hydrated" id="ion-overlay-1" no-router="" aria-modal="true" tabindex="-1" style="z-index: 20001;">
   <app-edit-position-modal _nghost-a-c317="" class="ion-page">
     <!--container--><!--container-->
   </app-edit-position-modal>
   <app-edit-position-modal _nghost-a-c317="" class="ion-page">
     <!--container--><!--container-->
   </app-edit-position-modal>
</ion-modal>
```

Even after I wait for the modal.present() or for some fakeAsync tick it won't contain anything I could test against.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to mock the `ModalController` and make it do what you want it to do with a `spy` or `SpyObj`. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50829780/7365461 and maybe this as well: https://grabthiscode.com/whatever/ionic-4-unit-testing-example-for-modalcontroller.

Comment: @AliF50 I don't wanna test if the .present() was called, I already do that in a unit test. This is for testing the integration between the page and the component in the modal.

Comment: For that, I am thinking you would have to provide the real `ModalController` and add `EditPositionModalComponent` to your declarations and then maybe see in the DOM after the promises and fixture.detectChanges() that `EditPositionModalComponent` is present. That being said, personally, I try to stay on the unit test side of things or on the end to end test side of things. My favorite framework for end to end testing is Cypress although there are many competitors out. Here is a video on end to end testing if you're interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAprpRyk0OI.

Comment: As I was reading the question I was forming an opinion similar to @AliF50 . Jasmine is for unit tests, IMO. Anything more is best suited to tools like Cypress. It has a pretty good visual editor that lets you "point and click" your tests which you can then edit further in your favorite IDE.